# HTML form action reference

Tags: django, html, forms

I was creating a website using html5 with django.I know that when action attribute is null in form it refers to the same url.So I tried it.But I cannot submit my action.So I used "#",instead of null in action attribute it worked.So I am confused about the two values in the attribute.So **Can anybody tell me what is the difference between action="" and action="#" in html form tag**

Comment: have a look into this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131781/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-an-empty-url-for-a-html-forms-action-attribute-a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

action="" will resolve to the page's address. action="#" will resolve to the page's address + #, which will mean an empty fragment identifier.

please check [what do <form action="#"> and <form method="post" action="#> do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395269/what-do-form-action-and-form-method-post-action-do)