# Delete objects in Django via html link

Tags: django

I have a project with a Post model, that is basic posts. I want to create a link on each post page to be able to delete that post (with appropriate security).

There are a few questions on this on stack overflow, but I can't seem to find a complete, workable answer (I am using Django 1.7) that doesn't throw up errors when I implement it.

I have been able to implement a delete function which works ok, but need to add a POST form with CSRF token for validation, and also check that the user deleting it is the one that created it. I can't seem figure out how to add these two in.

So far, in my views.py:

```
def delete(request, id):
    post = Post.objects.filter(pk=id).delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('posts.views.all_posts'))
```

In urls.py:

```
url(r'^delete/(?P<id>\d+)/$','posts.views.delete'),
```

In html:

```
<a href="/delete/{{ post.id }}">Delete</a>
```

This all works, but there is no security - so appreciate guidance on how to add a form and checking.

Also, I've seen an answer that uses DeleteView, but couldn't get that one to work either.

Comment: I just want to clarify if the users are required to be login to view all the posts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Indeed, using a GET method to delete your objects makes you vulnerable to [CSRF attacks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/).

[`DeleteView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#deleteview) only deletes on POST, and shows a confirmation page on GET.

Your code should look something like this in `views.py`:

```
from django.views.generic import DeleteView

class PostDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Post
    success_url = reverse_lazy('posts.views.all_posts')
```

In `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', PostDelete.as_view(),
        name='entry_delete'),
```

Your form (without using a confirmation template. There is an example of confirmation template in the docs):

```
<form action="{% url 'entry_delete' object.pk %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

If you are not using a confirmation template, make sure to point the form's `action` attribute to the `DeleteView` ([this is why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395269/)).

To ensure the user deleting the post is the user that owns it, I like to use [mixins](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/mixins/). Assuming your `Post` model has a `created_by` foreign key pointing to `User`, you could write a mixin like:

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied

class PermissionMixin(object):

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = super(PermissionMixin, self).get_object(*args, **kwargs)
        if not obj.created_by == self.request.user:
            raise PermissionDenied()
        else:
            return obj
```

Finally, your `DeleteView` should inherit from this mixin:

```
class PostDelete(PermissionMixin, DeleteView):

    model = Post
    success_url = reverse_lazy('posts.views.all_posts')
```

Comment: Brilliant, that worked perfectly - I tried it without the confirmation screen and it works really well. I'll try now to add in the confirmation screen.

Comment: For anyone looking at this in the future, you also need to import PostDelete in your urls.py eg: from views import PostDelete