# How can I delete a single file in Django?

Tags: django, file

I have a template which displays the files that a user has uploaded. I managed to make a view that allows me do delete all the files the user has uploaded, but I also would like to make it possible to delete each one individually.

I have a bootstrap card, and in the body I display each file with the delete link on the right:

```html
<div class="card-body text-light">
                {% for doc in docs %}

                <ul>
                    <a href="/media/{{doc}}" download style="color:lightblue"><font face="Ubuntu">{{doc.document|filename}}</font></a>
                    <a href="#"><font face="Ubuntu" color="red">Delete</font></a>
                </ul>&nbsp;
                {%endfor%}
            </div>
```

And in the card footer I use the view that deletes all files:

```html
<div class="card-footer bg-transparent border-light">
                <a href="{% url 'main:delete' %}"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt" style="color:red"></i> <font face="Ubuntu" color="red"><b>Delete All Files</b></font></a>
            </div>
```

My delete view is as follows:

```
def delete(request, **kwargs):
documents = Document.objects.filter(owner=request.user.id)
documents.delete()
cleanup_post_delete.connect(delete, request)

return redirect('main:user_panel')
```

The problem is, I can't figure how to delete each file individually, thought of using the objects.get() method but it really can't help me. I would need some view that targets that specific file and deletes it.

UPDATE:

So, here is how I managed the problem:

I made another view called delete_single:

```
def delete_single(request, id):
document = Document.objects.get(pk=id)
document.delete(id)
return redirect('main:user_panel')
```

But that wasn't enough, so by searching a bit I found a way around, these two classes will help in terms of security, since I found out that otherwise my file objects may be susceptible to CSRF attacks (not that would matter right now for me, since this is just a project of mine and I don't plan anything special with it, but I take it as good practice anyways):

```
class PermissionMixin(object):

def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = super(PermissionMixin, self).get_object(*args, **kwargs)
    if not obj.owner == self.request.user:
        raise PermissionDenied()
    else:
        return obj


class PostDelete(PermissionMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Document
    success_url = reverse_lazy('main:user_panel')
```

Also in urls.py:

```
url(r'^delete_single/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.PostDelete.as_view(), name='delete_single')
```

And finally in my template:

```html
<form action="{% url 'main:delete_single' doc.pk %}" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Delete" />
                    </form>
```

Comment: "I would need some view that targets that specific file and deletes it". Exactly. In that view you take the `id` of the object, do the `get()` and then delete it. [It should probably be a `POST` too, and not a `GET`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26153825/delete-objects-in-django-via-html-link). You _could_ have a single view that also takes care of deleting all the posts, given some input (e.g. checkboxes), that's a matter of choice and design.

Comment: I'll try that..

Comment: Did you try? Post your code as answer if it was a success, or update question with code.

Comment: Yes, I managed to do it, I'll post the solution in a second

Comment: Just edited it.