# How to call view function via button from template in Django?

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

I've searched some of the related questions and I couldn't figure out how to do it. That is why I am posting a new question here.

I have a `base.html` file and there is a button which should run a function from `views.py` file. Here is the button code:

```
<form role="form" action="" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
  <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Click" name="mybtn">
</form>
```

And here is my function from `views.py` file:

```
def create_new_product(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        '''Execute the code here'''
    return render (request, 'products/base.html')
```

And in my `Products`' `urls.py` file:

```
app_name = 'products'
urlpatterns = [
    path('create-new-product/', views.create_new_product),
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='base'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
]
```

Normally I have an `IndexView` class in `views.py` file which lists all the current products and what I expect from the above function is that it will generate new products and new products will also be listed in 'products' page.

The above function is not inside the `IndexView` class by the way.

Comment: Well by writing `action="#"`, you stay on the same page, regardless what the request returns: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395269/what-do-form-action-and-form-method-post-action-do

Comment: I removed # from there but the function does not work. I do not see any new products generated. Normally the function works. Now I am only trying to bind it to a button on the products page. By the way, I also checked the link you shared, thank you for that.

Comment: Are you sure you send it to the correct view. I find creating a new element with a get very strange (it is actually breaking the contract that a GET should not have any side-effects at all).

Comment: I am not sure. I think the 'name' attribute is the key there and I can bind the button click request with this key to the function. That is why I used this 'mybtn' in the function inside get. I am very new to it.

Comment: I'm saying that this is completely against how HTTP is supposed to work, a GET request should be *idempotent*, meaning that if I refresh thousands of times, the database is exactly the same as before: https://spring.io/understanding/REST#get

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. In my case, the database will generate thousands of copy if I click the button a thousands of times? However I think this problem will be my second problem because I couldn't solve the button click operation.

Comment: I found the problem. I updated my question too. I added Products' urls.py file in the question. I left the missing parts in the case that you may post the answer and I can accept it. There are two missing parts and the first one is that in Products' urls.py file `path('create-new-product/', views.create_new_product)` line should also have `name='create_new_product'` parameter. The second one is that in base.html file button action should like this  `action="{% url 'products:create_new_product' %}"`.

Answer (score 0):

You will stay on the same page with `action="#"`
Try instead `action=""` so you will stay on the same page but reloaded.
**Update:** 
Read your comment.
The name argument is useful to call your url in Django template like :

```
path('create-new-product/', views.create_new_product, name='create_new_product')
```

The app_name = 'products' is very important. It tells Django where to check your path. So you can call your view everywhere in your project by:

```
<a href="{% url 'products:create_new_product' %}">...</a>
<form action="{% url 'products:create_new_product' %}">...</form>
```

Comment: also `action=""` is equivalent to not mentioning it.

Comment: I tried but the function does not work. It seems that the button cannot give the command to the function.

Comment: Can I see your urls.py to check if you sent it to the right views

Comment: I added a new comment above. It shows the answer. You can check it. If you update your answer accordingly, I can accept it and so the other users can get benefit from this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can either use browser `fetch` api or jquery `ajax` to implement search functionality

1. include a `js` script to your template file
2. include this `js` snippet

```
$(elementSelector).on("click", async (e) => {
 const fetchOptions = {}
 const response = await fetch(YOUR_URL, {...fetchOptions});
 const responseUrl = response.url // see fetch api docs
 window.location = responseUrl // if you want to redirect
)
```