# Spring Controller accepts duplicate requests

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jsp

Whenever I send request to the server it takes duplicate entry in url.

For detailed description please see below example.

```
 @Controller
 @RequestMapping("v")
 public class ControllerDemo{

  @RequestMapping("test")
  public String view()
 {
    return "index.jsp";
 }

@RequestMapping("view")
public String view()
{
   return "login.jsp";
}
   }
```

---

**First request to Url: Https:localhost:8080/v/test**
When I go for a different request from test.jsp then it executes the following pattern **Https:localhost:8080/v/v/view**

---

In Test.jsp

```
    <form action="v/view">
       //Some data and submit
    </form>
```

It will send the request in url: https:localhost:8080/v/v/view instead of localhost:8080/v/view

*Please let me know if  you need to any other info or project configuration.*

Answer (score 1):

Just from the question itself it appears that the `action` tag's value is being appended to the path of the current page, so `https:localhost:8080/v + v/view` = `https:localhost:8080/v/v/view`.

Solution: change to just `<form action="view">`

This is backed up by the fact that `action=""` [points to the current page.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8395329/7123338)

Comment: Thank you, I was messed up with this. What if we want to go for different request so that it don't append the existing link, creating a new request like from localhost:8080/v/view to localhost:8080/user/my_account. 
Sometimes minor mistakes can mess you up LOL