# PHP post button on single page application

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

I am a newer developer and am working on my first single page application and have run into a problem. I am using JavaScript(jQuery really) to navigate within a single page of a WordPress page. I have been able to navigate successfully until I added a form with a POST method.

When the form is submitted, the PHP is sending the post request to the server, but then it refreshes the page, which changes the navigation to where the user starts on the application and not where the user pushed the form to see the results.

I have tried using window.location to push to a get request instead, but I was unable to produce anything different than with what I currently have. I have also tried finding a way to navigate purely in the PHP using a table of pages, but that doesn't seem effective. Here are a few snippets of my current code:

JavaScript

```
function c_check(div, check, output) {
   if ($(div).hasClass("active") && $(div).prop("innerText") == check) {
     $("#main").load(output);
   };
 };
 $(".side_menu_item").on( "click" , function(){
   $("#Menu1").addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("nav_active").siblings().removeClass("nav_active");
   nav_active = $(this).prop('id');
   if (nav_active == "Account") {
     $("#main").load(profile);
     $("#Menu1").prop("innerText","My Profile");
 $("#Menu2").prop("innerText","My Login Information");
 $("#Menu3").prop("innerText","My Positions");
   } else if .....
```

And the HTML:

```
<form method="post">
   <h1>Reset Your Password</h1>
     <input class="editable" type="password" name="old" placeholder="Current password"><br>
 <input class="editable" type="password" name="new" placeholder="New password"><br>
 <input class="editable" type="password" name="new_conf" placeholder="Confirm new password">
     <br>
 <button name="reset" class="press">Submit</button>
 </form>
 <?php
   if(isset($_POST['reset'])) {
     echo "<script>nav_active='Account'</script>";
     $old = $_POST['old'];
     $new_conf = $_POST['new_conf'];
     $new = $_Post['new'];
 if($old == $user_login->User_pass && $new == $new_conf) {
       WP_Query("UPDATE patches_users SET User_Pass=$new WHERE Member_ID=$mid;");
       echo "Your password has been reset.";
     }
   }
 ?>
```

Comment: Why not use ajax to post the data ?

Comment: How is navigation currently achieved, are you leveraging ids on your html elements? If so try setting the target id in the `action` attribute. Eg :`<form method="POST" action="#targetElementId">` . I've never tried using ID as the action attribute before, but it [should work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8395283/4665).

Comment: @KenLee, I haven't used Ajax before. I will study up. Thanks.